# Lucene query with same term exact, wildcard and fuzzy match

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to get Lucene results by Title first exact, then Title wildcard, then Title fuzzy, then by FieldX wildcard, then by FieldX fuzzy, ... but results are not in expected order (fuzzy results are higher).

Query:

```
Title:term^3 Title:term*^2 $"Title:term^1.9~ Field1:term*^1.6 Field1:term^1.5~ Field2:term*^1.4 Field2:term^1.3~...
```

How can I get needed results ordering with Lucene?

Comment: Have you tried sorting the results by result score?

Comment: Example: Searching: viking
Title:{term}^3 Title:{term}*^2 Title:{term}^1.1~  

Scooby-Doo and the Goblin King 
Score: 0.1855086 

Title: Vikingai [a lot of other words] 
Score:0.1531087

Comment: Try putting the tilde operator next to the term followed by the boost factor. Eg. instead of Field1:term^1.5~ write it as Field1:term~^1.5 Does that improve things?  Also, you might try using more exaggerated boost values.

Comment: Searching: viking. Same results(fuzzy rezults higher than wildcard)
Title:{term}^3 Title:{term}*^2 Title:{term}~^1.1 

Scooby-Doo and the Goblin King 
Score
0.1854779 
Vikingai [other words] 
Score
0.1531033

Comment: How about exaggerating the boost factors? eg.  Title:{term}^10 Title:{term}*^5 Title:{term}~^1

Comment: With query "Title:{term}^10 Title:{term}*^5 Title:{term}~^1" 
getting incorrect results:
Title
ian king live 
Score
0.09269757 

Title
Vikingai [other words]
Score
0.08368826 
-----------
With query: "Title:{term}^100 Title:{term}*^50 Title:{term}~^1" results so far as expected. Seems it can be solved
 with boost factors x10 (or maybe there is other way?).

Comment: Cool, at least with a large enough boost factor it works.  I grant you that feels a bit hacky.  Seems like their ought to be a better way, something that causes the scores to implicitly factor in the kind of match that was made (exact, wildcard, fuzzy, etc) but if that's possible I'm not advanced enough at Lucene to know how to do that.  If you find a way be sure to post that as an answer.  Glad exaggerated boosting gets you a solution though.